# AVComposition doesn't play via Airplay Video

Tags: ios, avfoundation

My AVMutableComposition which contains two locally stored video files plays fine on the iPad but cannot play via AirPlay Video.

My AVPlayer implementation works fine for regular AVURLAssets over AirPlay Video, just not for AVComposition assets.

Both locally stored video files play fine via Airplay Video when loaded as individual AVURLAssets.

Is this a limitation with AirPlay Video?  Or is there something I need to do to the composition?

Comment: I am not entirely sure if there is such general limitation but I do certainly know that AirPlay is really picky when it comes to encoding of video-content. Stuff that is playable totally fine on the device player is not always AirPlayable.

Comment: so did you get it to play ..?

Comment: did you get to play it finally?

Comment: The problem still exists, years later :(

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: Stack in the same problem. LOL

Comment: Issue still exists.